# codeigniter multiple or where, disregards the where not

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to create a list of users in the database of volunteers, based on those who are active members, and which jobs they volunteer for.

problem is, it is including inactive members as well.

Here is my controller

```
function View_Vol_LIST()
{
$data = array();

    if($query = $this->report_model->Volunteer_list())
    {
        $data['records'] = $query;
    }
$data['main_content'] = 'volunteer_list';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

Here is my model

```
function Volunteer_list()
{
    $query = $this->db->order_by('Last_Name', "ASC");
    $query = $this->db->order_by('First_Name', "ASC");
    $query = $this->db->where('Membership_Status !=', 'DNR');
    $query = $this->db->where('Vol_FA =', 'yes');
    $query = $this->db->or_where('Vol_TEL =', 'yes');
    $query = $this->db->or_where('Vol_CD =', 'yes');
    $query = $this->db->or_where('Vol_SCBA =', 'yes');
    $query = $this->db->or_where('Vol_MAIL =', 'yes');
    $query = $this->db->or_where('Vol_SML =', 'yes');
    $query = $this->db->or_where('Vol_BODCOM =', 'yes');
    $query = $this->db->or_where('Vol_OTHER =', 'yes');
    $query = $this->db->get('Membership');
    return $query->result();
```

It seems that the or_where is completely overriding the where != DNR (Did not Renew)

Help!

Thanks!

Comment: Echo this->db->last_query() I bet the logic isn't how you expect it you'll likely have to manually write it to get parenthesis in the right places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as nested queries like yours in Active Record is not allowed in Codeigniter

```
public function Volunteer_list(){
    $this->db->order_by('Last_Name', "ASC");
    $this->db->order_by('First_Name', "ASC");
    $this->db->where('Membership_Status !=', 'DNR');
    $this->db->where("(Vol_FA='yes'
                       OR Vol_TEL = 'yes'
                       OR Vol_CD='yes'
                       OR Vol_SCBA='yes'
                       OR Vol_MAIL='yes'
                       OR Vol_SML='yes'
                       OR Vol_BODCOM ='yes'
                       OR Vol_OTHER ='yes')", NULL, FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get('Membership');
    return $query->result();
}
```

The `NULL` is value parameter in that query and `FALSE` is to remove query quotes.

That will produce this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`Membership`) 
WHERE `Membership_Status` != 'DNR' 
AND (Vol_FA='yes' 
     OR Vol_TEL = 'yes' 
     OR Vol_CD='yes' 
     OR Vol_SCBA='yes' 
     OR Vol_MAIL='yes' 
     OR Vol_SML='yes' 
     OR Vol_BODCOM ='yes' 
     OR Vol_OTHER ='yes')
ORDER BY `Last_Name` ASC, `First_Name` ASC
```

Comment: then there is no data that means or you forgot something, check this fiddle for working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/483591/1/0

Comment: I'm sorry guys, forgot the return $query->result(); Pretty stupid of me, works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Hope it will help you.

```
function Volunteer_list()
{
    $this->db->order_by('Last_Name', "ASC")
            ->order_by('First_Name', "ASC")
            ->where('Membership_Status !=', 'DNR')
            ->group_start()
            ->where('Vol_FA =', 'yes')
            ->or_where('Vol_TEL =', 'yes')
            ->or_where('Vol_CD =', 'yes')
            ->or_where('Vol_SCBA =', 'yes')
            ->or_where('Vol_MAIL =', 'yes')
            ->or_where('Vol_SML =', 'yes')
            ->or_where('Vol_BODCOM =', 'yes')
            ->or_where('Vol_OTHER =', 'yes')
            ->group_end();
    
    $query = $this->db->get('Membership');
    return $query->result();
}
```

That will produce this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`Membership`) 
WHERE `Membership_Status` != 'DNR' 
AND (Vol_FA='yes' 
     OR Vol_TEL = 'yes' 
     OR Vol_CD='yes' 
     OR Vol_SCBA='yes' 
     OR Vol_MAIL='yes' 
     OR Vol_SML='yes' 
     OR Vol_BODCOM ='yes' 
     OR Vol_OTHER ='yes')
ORDER BY `Last_Name` ASC, `First_Name` ASC
```